# Is it the equivalent of doing CBC mode with a null iv?

Tags: c++, encryption, blowfish

If I initialize a IV with 8 null bytes. It makes block size equal to 8 (I think) and I could this code using CBC instead of ECB? Is that code equivalent of using CBC mode? Could we remove the loop if I use CBC? The key is 16 bytes long. I'm not encrypting the data, I receive it.

```
BF_KEY key = {{0}};
BF_set_key(&key, 16, key_data);

const int block_size = 8;
unsigned char previous[block_size] = {0}, decrypted[block_size] = {0};

for (auto it = replay_data.begin(); it != replay_data.end(); it += block_size) {
    BF_ecb_encrypt(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(*it)), decrypted, &key, BF_DECRYPT);
    std::transform(previous, previous + block_size, decrypted, decrypted, std::bit_xor<unsigned char>());
    std::copy_n(decrypted, block_size, previous);
    std::copy_n(decrypted, block_size, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&(*it)));
}
```

Comment: IVs need to be chosen randomly!  If you do not choose a random IV, then data about the plaintext is leaked.  The most basic leak is that if two plaintexts start out with the same block, then they encrypt to the same block, which is exactly the property that CBC is trying to avoid (and this is why ECB is insecure).

Comment: @TheGreatContini I'm not the one who is encrypting the data. The encrypted data is sent that way.

Comment: Then an IV should be part of the encrypted data.  Typically it is the first block of the encrypted data.  You do not want a null IV!  I think you need to make your question more clear.  How are they encrypting the data?  Are they using CBC or ECB?  If they are using ECB, then you ought to tell them how insecure it is.

Comment: @TheGreatContini, it's almost-but-not-quite CBC because it's chaining on the plaintext rather than the ciphertext.  This creates some interesting information leak possibilities, such as having any block that happens to be identical to its previous block result in the same ciphertext for the same key: to wit, the ECB-ciphertext of a block of zeroes.  This design definitely has issues, but the OP seems to be stuck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CBC with a fixed IV is not equivalent to ECB.

ECB processes each block in isolation:

[image]

On the other hand, CBC effectively uses each block of ciphertext as the next block's IV:

[image]

Assuming I'm reading the code correctly, your loop appears to be performing the XOR operation with the previous block's *plaintext* rather than its *ciphertext*, since you are copying from `decrypted` to `previous` *after* performing the decrypt and XOR step.  I don't believe this corresponds to any well-known cipher mode, so I'm somewhat at a loss for an image here.

Comment: I know that part, the thing is, in the loop I clearly see a xor with the previous data, which look alot like CBC mode, is it not?

Comment: @Maxime, it's similar but not identical.  Your loop xors with the already-decrypted form of the previous data block, while CBC xors with the previous encrypted block as given.  (Assuming I read it correctly...)